# Android Cipher AES/GCM/NoPadding "iv==null"

Tags: android, encryption, initialization-vector, aes-gcm

Trying to encrypt and decrypt some data, on Marshmallow. Encryption works well, but when trying to decrypt, I'm getting a RuntimeException, saying "iv == null".

Basically, cipher.getIV() and cipher.getParameters() returns null.
Am I missing something?

```
  private static final String ALGORITHM_NAME = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
  private static final int IV_SIZE = 128;
  private static final int ALGORITHM_SIZE = 256;

  private static final String KEYSTORE_PROVIDER = "AndroidKeyStore";
  private static final String SYMMETRIC_ALIAS = "secret_key";

  private static SecretKey getSymmetricKey()
      throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException,
      CertificateException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
    ks.load(null);

    return (SecretKey) ks.getKey(SYMMETRIC_ALIAS, null);
  }

  private static SecretKey createSecretKey()
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);

    keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(SYMMETRIC_ALIAS,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .setKeySize(ALGORITHM_SIZE)
        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
        .build());

    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
  }

  public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data)
      throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
      KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException,
      InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    SecretKey secretKey = getSymmetricKey();
    if (secretKey == null) {
      secretKey = createSecretKey();
    }

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_NAME);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
  }

  public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data)
      throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
      KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException,
      InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    SecretKey secretKey = getSymmetricKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_NAME);
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(IV_SIZE, cipher.getIV());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);
    return cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
  }
```

Comment: i am facing similar issue, can you please help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must to provide a non-null IV to AES/GCM/NoPadding `Cipher.init` when decrypting. However, your code provides a `null` IV, obtained by invoking `Cipher.getIV()` on an uninitialized `Cipher` instance.

The fix is to save the IV used when encrypting, and then use that same saved IV when decrypting.

Comment: The IV doesn't need to be secret, but it must be unique for GCM. Since it has always the same length, you can simply prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.